# QEMU and floating point - QEMU seems to stop

Tags: floating-point, qemu

I'm writing some code for a small kernel. I'm using QEMU to test the result:

qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -m 2048 -cpu host,+topoext -smp cores=8 -cdrom $(ISO_FILE) -vga cirrus -serial file:tmp/qemu-log.txt -D ./tmp/qemu-debug.txt -d in_asm &

With any double or float declaration (!) in the code:

`double blabla = 1.23;`

the emulation just stops in front of the declaration.

I removed the double declaration:

`//double blabla = 1.23;`

and the processing runs to the end as expected.

I tried adding flag to QEMU such as

`+fpu`

but without the expected result (code to be emulated with floating point declaration.

Comment: I suspect what has happened is not "emulation just stops" but "the emulation is correctly taking an exception when it encounters a floating point instruction". Check that (1) your bare metal binary does something useful on unexpected exceptions, like print a message about them and (2) your startup code does anything x86 requires you to do to enable the FPU and SSE before jumping into C code. After that, look at what the compiler is actually emitting, and check that it's not using something your host CPU doesn't implement; but it's probably a missing enable.